# Delete randomly selected N documents in a collection (MongoDB)

Tags: python, mongodb

Could anybody please tell me what's the elegant way you would delete N randomly selected documents in a collection in a MongoDB database (through Python ideally)? I would like to use somewhat concise like this

```
db.users.remove({ $sample: { size: N } })
```

But this one doesn't parse and I couldn't find a working alternative anywhere else . Many thanks!

Comment: Please add some code you tried before asking how to do something. Unfortunately, SO is not a code writing service. Asking questions in this fashion is a sure way to get downvoted,

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am an utter newbie here. Will write smthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregation to get your sample and store _id values to a list:

```
list_of_ids=list(db.users.aggregate([{'$sample': {'size': 10 }}, {'$project' : {'_id' : 1}} ]))
```

use delete_many to drop sample documents

```
results = db.users.delete_many({'_id: {'$in': list_of_ids}})
```

(*) make sure to check here for limitations of [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)